# Finding columns with Null values and write them in a new column per each record in Pyspark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a scenario, where I have to find columns with Null values per each record, and write all such column names into a separate column.

Example:
I have this DataFrame:

```
+---------+---+------------+-----------+------+-------+
|firstName|age|jobStartDate|isGraduated|gender| salary|
+---------+---+------------+-----------+------+-------+
|     null|se3|  2006-01-01|          8|     M|      F|
|     null| a3|        null|       True|     F|   null|
|   Robert| 37|  1992-01-01|       null|     M|5000.50|
+---------+---+------------+-----------+------+-------+
```

Expected result should be like the one below:

```
+---------+---+------------+-----------+------+-------+----------------------+
|firstName|age|jobStartDate|isGraduated|gender| salary|       Missing Columns|
+---------+---+------------+-----------+------+-------+----------------------+
|     null|se3|  2006-01-01|          8|     M|      F|             firstName|
|     null| a3|  2006-01-02|       True|     F|   null|      firstName,salary|
|   Robert| 37|  1992-01-01|       null|     M|5000.50|           isGraduated|
+---------+---+------------+-----------+------+-------+----------------------+
```

I have written code which half meets my expected results:

```
def find_exceptions(df,mand_cols = ['firstName','jobStartDate','salary']):
  miss = "Missing: "
  for column in mand_cols:
    if df[column] is None:
      miss = miss + column + ","
  return miss
```

I am able to collect the missing values as list:

```
temp = sourceDF.rdd.map(find_exceptions)
temp.collect()
#result: 
['Missing: firstName,', 'Missing: firstName,jobStartDate,salary,', 'Missing: ']
```

I am finding it difficult to actually write this into a new column. I am fairly new to Spark and would really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in three steps.

Step 1: Create an array of size number of columns. If an entry is null, then set the respective element in array as the name of column name, else leave the value null.

Step 2: Filter the array for column names

Step 3: Concatenate to have comma-separated list

```
df //step 1
    .withColumn("MissingColumns",
      array(
        when(col("firstName").isNull(),lit("firstName")),
        when(col("age").isNull(),lit("age")),
        when(col("jobStartDate").isNull(),lit("jobStartDate")),
        when(col("isGraduated").isNull(),lit("isGraduated")),
        when(col("gender").isNull(),lit("gender")),
        when(col("salary").isNull(),lit("salary"))
      )
    )
     //step 2
      .withColumn("MissingColumns",expr("filter(MissingColumns, c -> c IS NOT NULL)"))
     //step 3
      .withColumn("MissingColumns",concat_ws(",",col("MissingColumns")) )
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Please correct isNull to isNull(), so that I can mark it as correct answer.

Comment: my bad. I ran the code in scala. isNull() should indeed have the parenthesis in python.

Comment: I have tried to form the condition in first .withColumn() through for loop and using it instead of writing the whole condition manually. But it is not working. Can you suggest me an alternative?

Comment: it is possible to write it as a loop, replace the array-statement with this:

array(*[when(col(c).isNull(),lit(c)) for c in columns])